# Mix of Repository and UOW For Business Library with Entity Per Table Architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I am trying to use Entity framework along with UOW in business class where I want to use this layer across multiple types of applications like web, webapi and Windows Services. So I cooked something from the online resources. Can some one figure out any potential performance or fallback?

Main reason I am trying to write this way is to use this across multiple application layers with out dealing Entities across them. Now all I have to do is add reference to the application and use them as written at the bottom.

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this to commit the unit of work
        /// </summary>
        void Commit();

        /// <summary>
        /// Return the database reference for this UOW
        /// </summary>
        DbContext Db { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts a transaction on this unit of work
        /// </summary>
        void StartTransaction();


    }


public interface IBaseRepository<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve a single item using it's primary key, exception if not found
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="primaryKey">The primary key of the record</param>
        /// <returns>T</returns>
        T Single(object primaryKey);
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve created by and modified by id's FullName
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dynamicObject">The primary key of the record</param>
        /// <returns>T</returns>
        Dictionary<string, string> GetAuditNames(dynamic dynamicObject);
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve a single item by it's primary key or return null if not found
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="primaryKey">Prmary key to find</param>
        /// <returns>T</returns>
        T SingleOrDefault(object primaryKey);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all the rows for type T
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();

        /// <summary>
        /// Does this item exist by it's primary key
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="primaryKey"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        bool Exists(object primaryKey);

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts the data into the table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">The entity to insert</param>
        /// <param name="userId">The user performing the insert</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        void Insert(T entity);

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates this entity in the database using it's primary key
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">The entity to update</param>
        /// <param name="userId">The user performing the update</param>
        void Update(T entity);



        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes this entry fro the database
        /// ** WARNING - Most items should be marked inactive and Updated, not deleted
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">The entity to delete</param>
        /// <param name="userId">The user Id who deleted the entity</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        int Delete(T entity);

        IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }



    }
```

Abstract Classes

```
public class AbstractUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
         private TransactionScope _transaction;
        private DbContext _db;


        public AbstractUnitOfWork(DbContext targetContext)
        {
            _db = targetContext;

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_db != null)
                {
                    _db.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        public void StartTransaction()
        {
            _transaction = new TransactionScope();
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
            _transaction.Complete();
        }

        public DbContext Db
        {
            get { return _db; }
        }
    }




 public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>
        where T : class
    {
        private  IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        internal DbSet<T> dbSet;

        public BaseRepository()
        {
        }

        public BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            if (unitOfWork == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            this.dbSet = _unitOfWork.Db.Set<T>();
        }


        public BaseRepository(DbContext targetContext)
        {
            if (targetContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("TargetContext");
            _unitOfWork = new AbstractUnitOfWork(targetContext);
            this.dbSet = _unitOfWork.Db.Set<T>();            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the object with the primary key specifies or throws
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TU">The type to map the result to</typeparam>
        /// <param name="primaryKey">The primary key</param>
        /// <returns>The result mapped to the specified type</returns>
        public T Single(object primaryKey)
        {

            var dbResult = dbSet.Find(primaryKey);
            return dbResult;

        }


        public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return _unitOfWork.Db.Set<T>().AsNoTracking<T>().Where(where);
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the object with the primary key specifies or the default for the type
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TU">The type to map the result to</typeparam>
        /// <param name="primaryKey">The primary key</param>
        /// <returns>The result mapped to the specified type</returns>
        public T SingleOrDefault(object primaryKey)
        {
            var dbResult = dbSet.Find(primaryKey);
            return dbResult;
        }





        public bool Exists(object primaryKey)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(primaryKey) == null ? false : true;
        }

        public virtual void Insert(T entity)
        {
            dynamic obj = dbSet.Add(entity);
            this._unitOfWork.Db.SaveChanges();
            //return obj.ID;
        }

        public virtual void Update(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
            _unitOfWork.Db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            this._unitOfWork.Db.SaveChanges();
        }


        public virtual void Insert(DbContext targetContext)
        {
            if (targetContext != null)
            {               
                this.dbSet = targetContext.Set<T>();
            }
            if (dbSet == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("No Unit of Work Context available for processing the CRUD Operation");
            }
            dynamic obj = dbSet.Add((T)(object)this);           
            targetContext.SaveChanges();
        }


        public virtual void Update(DbContext targetContext)
        {
            if (targetContext != null)
            {               
                this.dbSet = targetContext.Set<T>();
            }
            if (dbSet ==null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("No Unit of Work Context available for processing the CRUD Operation");
            }
            dbSet.Attach((T)(object)this);            
            targetContext.Entry((T)(object)this).State = EntityState.Modified;
            targetContext.SaveChanges();

        }


        public virtual int Delete(DbContext targetContext)
        {
            if (targetContext != null)
            {
                _unitOfWork = new AbstractUnitOfWork(targetContext);
                this.dbSet = _unitOfWork.Db.Set<T>();
            }
            if (dbSet == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("No Unit of Work Context available for processing the CRUD Operation");
            }
            if (_unitOfWork.Db.Entry((T)(object)this).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach((T)(object)this);
            }
            dynamic obj = dbSet.Remove((T)(object)this);
            this._unitOfWork.Db.SaveChanges();
            return obj.Id;
        }

        public int Delete(T entity)
        {
            if (_unitOfWork.Db.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entity);
            }         
            dynamic obj = dbSet.Remove(entity);
            this._unitOfWork.Db.SaveChanges();
            return obj.Id;
        }
        public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get { return _unitOfWork; } }
        internal DbContext Database { get { return _unitOfWork.Db; } }
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetAuditNames(dynamic dynamicObject)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return dbSet.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }

    }
```

Entity Classes (Partial classes of the edmx generated)

```
 partial class MyClass : BaseRepository<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass(DbContext context):base(context)
    {


    }
    public static MyClass GetByOrgID(long id)
    {
        return MyClass.Instance.Find(org => org.OrganizationID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static MyClass GetByOrgGuid(Guid orgGuid)
    {
        return MyClass.Instance.Find(org => org.OrgGuid == orgGuid).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static MyClass GetOrgDetailsbyEmail(string email)
    {
        return MyClass.Instance.Find(o => o.OrgEmail == email).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static MyClass[] GetEverythingAll()
    {
        return MyClass.Instance.GetAll().ToArray();
    }

    public static bool IsEmailAlreadyExists(string email)
    {
        return (MyClass.Instance.Find(org => org.OrgEmail == email).FirstOrDefault() != null ? true : false);
    }

    public static long GetOrgIdbyEmail(string email)
    {
        long orgId = 0;
        MyClass org = MyClass.Instance.Find(o => o.OrgEmail == email).FirstOrDefault();
        if(org != null)
            orgId = org.OrganizationID;

        return orgId;
    }

    public static long GetOrgIdbyGuid(Guid orgGuid)
    {
        long orgId = 0;
        MyClass org = MyClass.Instance.Find(o => o.OrgGuid == orgGuid).FirstOrDefault();
        if (org != null)
            orgId = org.OrganizationID;

        return orgId;
    }    

    #region Singleton

    private static MyClass _instance = null;
    private static readonly object _padlock = new object();
    public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_padlock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new MyClass(new OrganizationEntities());
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }


    #endregion Singleton

}
```

Retrieving and updating records from any application layer looks like

```
/Getting database record

        MyClass.Instance.GetByOrgID(20);

        // Save record code looks like
        private readonly DbContext _uowContext = new OrganizationEntities();
        MyClass newInstance = new MyClass();
        newInstance.OrgGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        newInstance.OrgName = reqOrg.OrgName;                
        newInstance.OrgEmail = reqOrg.OrgEmail;
        newInstance.OrgPhoneNumber1 = reqOrg.OrgPhoneNumber1;
        newInstance.OrgPhoneNumber2 = reqOrg.OrgPhoneNumber2;
        newInstance.OrgFaxNumber = reqOrg.OrgFaxNumber;                
        newInstance.IsActive = true;                
        newInstance.Insert(_uowContext);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's wrong. Your entity types are mixing concerns and are no longer simple POCO types, they now have incestuous knowledge of a `DbContext` (which can access every single entity type and the database itself, run stored procedures, ...*everything*).

Not only that, but you're working *against* Entity Framework, rather than *with* it: a `DbContext` **is** a unit-of-work, as it **already** encapsulates a transaction for you - and regardless of what people say, `IDbSet<T>` *is* a repository, at least as far as EF is concerned.

Consider:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Commit();
    IDbSet<T> Repository<T>();
}
```

A `DbContext` can very easily implement that interface:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    /* ...implementation details... */

    public IDbSet<T> Repository<T>()
    {
        return Set<T>();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Needing a `StartTransaction` method on a UoW feels weird at best, because *the sole purpose of a UoW is to encapsulate a transaction* - in an ideal world, you would only call `SaveChanges` once in its entire lifetime.

---

Your "abstract unit of work" isn't an `abstract` class, which makes things confusing.

Entity types should be Plain Old CLR Objects - simple classes with getters+setters; yours are full-fledged data access services, and to be honest I'm surprised Entity Framework can even work with those, given the absence of a default constructor and... the singleton.

How are you supposed to have an `IEnumerable<TEntity>` if `TEntity` is a singleton?

How does this even *compiles* without a default constructor?

> ```
> MyClass newInstance = new MyClass();
> ```

I'm *guessing* the default constructor is defined by the EDMX generated code, otherwise your code would never work. Point is, if a type has to have a default constructor, even *considering* making a singleton out of it is pointless.

Split responsibilities, let entity types be entity types, and write your `GetFooByBar` methods in some `FooService` class that receives an `IUnitOfWork` dependency in its constructor:

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public SomeService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public SomeEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return _uow.Repository<SomeEntity>().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    // ...
}
```

That way whoever is controlling the instantiation of `SomeService` gets to inject the `IUnitOfWork`, and if there are 20 such services, they can all get the same instance, and thus contribute to the same transaction.

Comment: How does this even compiles without a default constructor?

MyClass newInstance = new MyClass();

I am using it as partial class which is already an edmx entity.

Comment: @Krishna `public MyClass(DbContext context):base(context)` is the only constructor listed in `MyClass`; if the other half of the `partial` class didn't define a public parameterless constructor, `var foo = new MyClass();` could not compile.

Comment: That constructor is auto generated by EDMX in partial class. Infact it is working. But I see what you are coming from. Very good points.
Anyway, Can you suggest if there is a best way to encapsulate all these stuff into business library? I want to reuse it. I dont want to tag to a service.

Comment: That constructor entirely defeats the purpose of a singleton. As for exposing the functionality, it entirely depends on your architecture. I'm not sure what you mean with "I don't want to tag to a service"...

Comment: You are exactly right. I am using the singleton only to query the data. I was hoping to use only one instance responsible to query.

Comment: You *can* do that *if you need to* - but not on an *entity type*. An entity isn't *responsible to query*, it's responsible for holding an entity's property values, period. And there *needs* to be more than one single instance. Hence, you need to remove the "repository" functionality from the entity types.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you should set up a UoW/Repository layer on top of the UoW/Repository implementations that EF offers out of the box (`DbContext`/`DbSet`) is a question I consider beyond the scope of this review. You'll find many many opinions about this on the internet.

But a couple of things are definitely wrong.

#### Repository's internals

1. I don't understand why repositories insert, update and delete *themselves*. For example in the `Insert` method, you have:

   > ```
   > dynamic obj = this.dbSet.Add((T)(object)this);
   > ```

   What *is* this? This is either a copy/paste error or a major design flaw. How can a repository add itself to the `DbSet` it contains? And why the double(!) cast, why the `dynamic`? "Smelly" is an understatement.
2. Why is `BaseRepository`'s member `dbSet` internal? The repo is supposed to encapsulate a `DbSet`. What should other classes in the assembly do with it? If you *need* it to be internal, it's because of something you don't show, and which, again, would be a major design flaw.
3. One `Find` method returns untracked entities? (`AsNoTracking`), while `Single` and `GetAll` methods don't. That's confusing. It may be useful to have options for applying `AsNoTracking` or not, but a consumer of a repository should not have to *know* which methods do and which don't. Either the method name should reveal it, or it should be parametrized.
4. `GetAll` in its present form is a useless method. It returns ...

   > ```
   > this.dbSet.AsEnumerable().ToList()
   > ```

   ... that is: the entire database table. Other than for small tables, who's going to want that?
5. Don't save changes. Repositories shouldn't call `SaveChanges`. The Unit of Work is responsible for that. I know that you intend to wrap each repository operation into a `TransactionScope`, managed by the UoW, but if you remove these `SaveChanges`, the UoW doesn't need this `TransactionScope`: the single `SaveChanges` call in its `Commit` method will be enough to save all changes in one transaction.

#### Repository's public methods

1. As a loose definition, repositories are supposed to expose the database tables as collection-like interfaces to the application code. So it's expected for them to have `Insert`, `Update`, and `Delete` methods. But what's the use of a method like `Insert(DbContext targetContext)`? Remember that consumers of the repo only see the outside. They'll wonder "am I going to insert a context? And into what?" This is bad, but the really bad thing is that the method has vastly unexpected side effects: it replaces the context's `dbSet` by `targetContext.Set<T>`. How can consumers even begin to expect that to happen? Together with the first point above I don't understand *anything* of these methods receiving `DbContext` as a parameter.
2. No composability.

   OK, now if the above points wouldn't exist, you'd be left with a pretty regular repository. The only problem would then be that you can't use it to compose queries efficiently, because the "get" methods return `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`.

   Take this example:

   ```
     var results = from r1 in repo1.TableA.GetAll()
                   where r1.Id == someId
                   join r2 in repo2.GetAll() on r1.Id equals r2.TableAId
                   select new { ... };
   ```

   Returning `IEnumerable` has three major downsides:

   - No database filtering. As said above, `GetAll()` returns the full table content. Only after that the `where` is applied. An `IQueryables` would have pulled only one record from the database. Well, this point is alleviated somewhat by the `Find` method that accepts a predicate. But there's more.
   - Combined repositories execute separate queries. Both `GetAll()` methods run first and their results are joined in memory. Two `IQueryables` on the other hand, would create one expression that can be translated into one SQL call containing a `JOIN` and, obviously, the number of records from the second `GetAll()` would be limited. And this could not have been limited by using the `Find` with predicate, because there is no predicate. The `join` is a dynamic predicate, if you like.
   - No projection. The `select new` isn't translated back into a limited number of fields in the SQL `SELECT` statement.

**tl;dr** Together with the points mentioned in the other answer, *very* much is *very* wrong. Back to the drawing board. Or back to some generic repository implementation from the internet. They're all essentially identical.